# SAS is converting a character variable to numeric without being asked to

Tags: char, sas

I have the following SAS code:

```
DATA WORK.temp; 
SET WORK.proj;

RETAIN prev_time
       prev_name
       prev_type
       count 0;

FLAG = 0; 

IF( (prev_name = name) AND (prev_type NE type) AND (prev_type = 'x')) THEN DO; 
    TimeDifference = time - prev_time;
    IF( TimeDifference < 10*60) THEN DO;
        FLAG = 1;
        count + 1;
        END;
    END; 
prev_time = time;
prev_type = type;
prev_name = name;
RUN;
```

When I run the program I get notes telling me that my character values have been converted to numeric values:

NOTE: Character values have been converted to numeric values

NOTE: Invalid numeric data, name='somename'

NOTE: Invalid numeric data, name='othername'

I never asked SAS to make this conversion, and it is causing errors in the output. Any idea what is causing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most certainly did ask SAS to (implicitly).

```
RETAIN prev_time
       prev_name
       prev_type
       count 0;
```

That doesn't just set `count` to 0.  It sets *all four variables* to `0`, which is numeric.  So `prev_name` is numeric, and when you say `prev_name=name` (both in the `IF` statement and the assignment later) you get this note.

You can see this here:

```
data test;
  retain x y z 0;
  put x= y= z=;
run;
```

All three variables are initialized to 0, not just `z`.  The newline in your code doesn't have any meaning (as is normal in SAS).

Further, your `count` variable is automatically retained by using it in the fashion you did:

```
count+1;
```

The sum operator retains, AND works like `sum()`, which means that missing plus one is one (not missing).

So the simplest fix here is to remove `count 0` from the retain statement, and the rest should be fine as is.

Comment: Thanks @Joe. I had read the examples here: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000214163.htm, but now realize that I misinterpreted what they were saying. I'm guessing the fix is to put the count variable first? Extra points for being so speedy!

Comment: You would need two retain statements, or to remove the 0 intialization in the retain statement.  As it stands, you can remove the `count` variable from the retain entirely - it is automatically retained and not harmed by starting out missing.